# TWebBrowser auto login

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using the following code to fill in a username and a password into their respective fields on a website login form.

```
var

Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
I: Integer;
Element: OleVariant;
Elements: IHTMLElementCollection;
Sub: Variant;

begin

Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
Elements := Doc.All;
for I := 0 to Elements.length - 1 do begin
Element := Elements.item(I, varEmpty);

if (UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT') and (UpperCase(Element.Type) = 'TEXT') then begin
if (Element.name = 'user') then Element.value := 'theusername';

if (UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT') and (UpperCase(Element.Type) = 'PASSWORD') then begin
if (Element.name = 'passwrd') then Element.value := 'thepassword';
end;
end;
Sub := WebBrowser1.Document;
Sub.frmLogin.Submit();
end;
end;
```

Info on the respective fields:

[image]
[image]

What's happening when I run the code:

[image]

As you can see, the username part works, username gets inserted. The password field, however, doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'input'` and the next one do not look right - `UpperCase` won't match 'input'

Comment: @BrakNicku edited the question with the code, a typo on my part, sorry about that. Either way, it doesn't work, with or without Uppercase and so forth, same thing happens.

Comment: only the first (outer) `IF` is being checked each time in for loop

Comment: @BrakNicku nice catch, thanks, solved it now and it works!

Comment: The result of that might very well be just a POST request to the server. And `TWebBrowser` allows you to `Navigate` with POST data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very hard to see with the formatting in the question. Following is a copy of that code with - subjectively - better formatting. You might notice that the `end;` before you do something with Webbrowser1. That are the the closing `end;`s for your `if`s, they are therefore nested. And the password field will never be found as it doesn't match both conditions.

While code formatting is a matter of taste, some things can really help avoiding trouble and make the code more readable.

Orginal reformatted:

```
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  I: Integer;
  Element: OleVariant;
  Elements: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Sub: Variant;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Elements := Doc.All;
  for I := 0 to Elements.length - 1 do begin
    Element := Elements.item(I, varEmpty);

    if (UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT') and (UpperCase(Element.Type) = 'TEXT') then
    begin
      if (Element.name = 'user') then Element.value := 'theusername';

      if (UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT') and (UpperCase(Element.Type) = 'PASSWORD') then
      begin
        if (Element.name = 'passwrd') then Element.value := 'thepassword';
      end;
    end;
    Sub := WebBrowser1.Document;
    Sub.frmLogin.Submit();
  end;
end;
```

Logical issue resolved:

```
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  I: Integer;
  Element: OleVariant;
  Elements: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Sub: Variant;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Elements := Doc.All;
  for I := 0 to Elements.length - 1 do begin
    Element := Elements.item(I, varEmpty);

    if (UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT') and (UpperCase(Element.Type) = 'TEXT') then
    begin
      if (Element.name = 'user') then
        Element.value := 'theusername';
    end;
    if (UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT') and (UpperCase(Element.Type) = 'PASSWORD') then
    begin
      if (Element.name = 'passwrd') then
        Element.value := 'thepassword';
    end;
    Sub := WebBrowser1.Document;
    Sub.frmLogin.Submit();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Serves me right for using internet code and not checking and formatting it to my own style. Thanks, works.

Comment: Personally, I would use `IHTMLDocument3.getElementById()` or `IHTMLDocument3.getElementsByName()` to find the `<input>` elements, instead of iterating `Doc.all`. Or better, find the `<form>` element in the document, get its `IHTMLFormElement` interface, use its `item()` method to find the `<input>` elements, and call its `submit()` method directly without going through `Variant` at all.